# Prepend php divs

Tags: php, prepend

I have some php code that creates divs based on my database information. I want it to look through and show the newest first. I tried several things with no success. Any help is appreciated!

```
function filldiv() {
    $loopResult .= '';
    $events = mysql_query('SELECT * FROM a3825952_blog.Blog'); 
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($events)) { 
        $loopResult .= ' 
                <div class="blogbox"> 
                    <div class="blogtitle">'.$row['TITLE'].'</div> 
                    <div class="blogdate">'.$row['DATE'].'</div>                    
                    <div class="blogcontent">'.$row['CONTENT'].'</div> 
                    <div class="blogimage"> <img src="'.$row['IMAGE'].'"/></div> 
                    <div class="blogimage"> <img src="'.$row['IMAGEB'].'"/></div>
                    <div class="blogimage"> <img src="'.$row['IMAGEC'].'"/></div> 
                </div>              
        '; 
    } 
    echo $loopResult;
}
}
```

Comment: just use an `ORDER BY` on the date descending. and use mysqli or PDO instead

Comment: -0.49 for still using `mysql_query` in 2014.  Seriously, read up on PDO and/or mysqli.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use an ORDER BY clause in your select statement:

```
SELECT * FROM a3825952_blog.Blog ORDER BY `date` DESC
```

See http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_order_by.asp for some tutorials to start with.

Comment: Wow, so simple! Obviously I am still in the learning process. I appreciate the help and will make sure I take time to learn some PHP and SQL. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

You'll want to add `ORDER BY DATE DESC` to the end of your mysql query.

So: `$events = mysql_query('SELECT * FROM a3825952_blog.Blog ORDER BY DATE DESC');`

Hope this helps!